# Working cefsharp POST example

Tags: c#, chromium, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

Having a difficult time getting an HTTP POST request/response using cefsharp / ChromiumWebBrowser. I'm unable to find a working example on Stackoverflow, nor in the documentation.  Looking to see if anyone has a full example?  I'm stuck on if it can be done with a Navigate function (as show in one example), or needs to be a done with a handler / schema.

I'm trying a basic POST to a PHP script.  If the data1/data2 match the input, it's return json status:success, otherwise failure.  I see in the devtools that the html body comes back with json success, but this code returns  or nothing at all.  I've tried too different ways to get the response data.  I want to grab the JSON response for the C# code to review.  Surely there should be an easy way to accomplish this?  I want to send an HTTP request and then get the body (json) to parse.  If this needs the schema/handler, I cannot find a full example of using this.

```
namespace BrowserTest
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        ChromiumWebBrowser browser = null;

        public Loader()
        {
            browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("http://localhost/test/"); // Initialize to this page
            pBrowserLogin.Controls.Add(browser);
        }

        private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            byte[] request = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("data1=" + txtData1.Text + "&data2=" + txtData2.Text);
            PostTest.Navigate(browser, "http://localhost/test/posttest.php", request, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        }
    }
    public static class PostTest
    {
        public static void Navigate(this IWebBrowser browser, string url, byte[] postDataBytes, string contentType)
        {
            IFrame frame = browser.GetMainFrame();
            IRequest request = frame.CreateRequest();

            request.Url = url;
            request.Method = "POST";

            request.InitializePostData();
            var element = request.PostData.CreatePostDataElement();
            element.Bytes = postDataBytes;
            request.PostData.AddElement(element);

            NameValueCollection headers = new NameValueCollection();
            headers.Add("Content-Type", contentType);
            request.Headers = headers;

            frame.LoadRequest(request);

            frame.GetTextAsync().ContinueWith(taskHtml =>
            {
                var html = taskHtml.Result;
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(html);
            });

            string script = string.Format("document.documentElement.outerHTML;");
            frame.EvaluateScriptAsync(script).ContinueWith(x =>
            {
                var response = x.Result;

                if (response.Success && response.Result != null)
                {
                    var fullhtml = response.Result;
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(fullhtml.ToString());
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason your using CefSharp for this? You load the request, you don't wait for it to load.

Comment: There is part of the CEF API that might be better suited to this, not implemented in CefSharp as most people use the .net classes. You can try CefGlue or ChromiumFx. http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/(default)/CefURLRequest.html#Create(CefRefPtr<CefRequest>,CefRefPtr<CefURLRequestClient>,CefRefPtr<CefRequestContext>)